# My Google Account is closed as some reason, but we have 5-7 servers in GCP, how can I manage my GCP now

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have 5-7 servers in GCP and many other things in Google Stroge, but from yesterday, I find my google account is banned as some reason, so now I can not login my Google account, and can not login my GCP, we can not manage my servers and any other things. Even the servers are still running, but I can not manage them and I even can not see my spend or any other important thing.

I tried to connect to Google to get this account back, but after 2 days, Google give me the response that they reject to reopen it.

Any one met this issue before, for this GCP, I only have this google account can login to manage it. I can not find any solution in GCP support document, and there is no email address that I can send to get help.

As I know in the GCP panel, it allowed to add another Google account as an owner, but now I cannot login my old account, so I can not do it.

who can help us with it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it a private account or an organisation account?

Comment: Read [this](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-suspension-guidelines)

Comment: @mirana I think it's a priveate account.

Comment: Did you give anyone your credentials? sometimes people use the cloud to mine for bitcoins and abuse the system. Anyway, contact support as the 1 answer states! Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you @mirana, btw, if I use the "Support Contact Troubleshooter", which one I should choose "GCP Account and Resource Recovery Request" or "GCP Account Suspension Inquiry", for this case, my Goolge account is suspended, but I think the GCP account is okey. So I choose the first one, is it correct? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to communicate your issue to Google Cloud Platform through its Support. [Contact the billing support team](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing)  through a Support Ticket, Chat, Mail or Phone.

You may also report your issue with [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). Please make sure to file your ticket under the right component.